# c rotation through for loop and indices at the end

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

So I am a beginner and was trying to solve a question on rotating a array by d elements in C. My code works for general indices but whenever there is a transition from the last element to the first element i get an output though instead of showing the number 5(for eg:) it shows a large number 1969844117.
So the code i used is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,d;
    int i,j,tmp;
    int a[20];
    int b[20];

    printf("Input Size Of array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Input the rotation factor d:");
    scanf("%d",&d);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter a[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0,j=i+d;i<n,j<i+d;i++,j++){
        tmp=a[i];
        b[j]=tmp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So is there something i am not getting or what is the logic that im missing. How does the change of index at the end of the loop affect the characters being cycled through it?

Comment: In your for loop, `i<n,j<i+d` should be `i<n && j<i+d`

Comment: Please give an explicit example of what you passed for `n`, `d`, and the array. And then give the output that you got and the output that you expected. Like, given the array `[1,2,3,4]` and a rotation of `2`, I expected `[3,4,1,2]`, but got `[a,b,c,d]` instead.

Comment: the condition `i<n,j<i+d` (in 2nd `for` loop) does not work the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for loop`, you are trying to assign `b[j] where j can be greater than n` which defeats the purpose and the starting elements `b[j]` ,where  `j < d` remains unassigned, hence you get random numbers as output. Hence the below `for loop` is wrong.

```
for(i=0,j=i+d;i<n,j<i+d;i++,j++){
            tmp=a[i];
            b[j]=tmp;
        }
```

You can avoid using two different variables in single for loop (which is itself an example of bad programming) by using nested loops.
Here's correct code:

```
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            j=i+d;
        tmp=a[i];
        b[j%n]=tmp;
    }
```

Here, when `j >= n` then using `j%n`, j will be assigned start index of array `j = 0,1,2,3 and so on`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, your rotation `for` loop doesn't make much sense, with the pointless (sorry for that) usage of the variable `tmp` to begin with.

Depending on your desired rotation direction, I would suggest:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b[i] = a[(i + d) % n];
}
```

or

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b[i] = a[(i + n - d) % n];
    // or: b[(i + d) % n] = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't need to maintain the storage of numbers further, once the elements corresponding to the displacement (that will be output at the end) have been printed, we print the first read elements and saved in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int rotation;

    int N;

    /* this is not necessary, we can be reading as far as we
     * continue having input.  We print the saved entries
     * after input has been exausted */
    fprintf(stderr, "Number of entries: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    fprintf(stderr, "Rotation shift: ");
    scanf("%d", &rotation);

    int *array = malloc(rotation * sizeof *array);
    
    /* all these elements go at the end */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rotation; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }

    /* print the elements past the header that we'll put at the end */
    if (i >= rotation) {
        int value;
        N -= i;
        while (N-- > 0 && scanf("%d", &value) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n", value);
        }
    } else {
        rotation = i;
    }

    /* print the heading ones at end. */
    for (i = 0; i < rotation; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

and you don't need to consume a full array for all the input.  In case you want a negative displacement (the elements of the tail at the beginning) you just add `N` to that number and you'll get the correct output (a rotation of `-d` is the same as a rotation of `N - d`, so it suffices to add `N` or subtract `N` to the number, until it is between `0` and `N-1`, both included)